# Update with function for value only seems to evaluate the function once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to change all the NULLs in an INT column to an incrementing value using a statement like this:

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET [ColumnName] = dbo.FunctionName() WHERE [ColumnName] IS NULL
```

where the function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionName() RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (select MAX(ColumnName) + 1 from TableName)
END
```

but the result of this is that all the values that were NULL are now set to the same value (i.e. 1 greater than the max *before* the statement was called).

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, how would I go about getting the result I'm after?

I'd like to avoid using an auto-increment column as all I *really* want is uniqueness, the incrementing is just a way of getting there.

Comment: You'll get the result you're after by using an autoincrement column. Your reason for not wanting to use one applies just as much to your hack as it does to the actual working autoincrement.

Comment: @Anon: the values in this column are unique identifiers defined outside our system, which definitely aren't auto-incrementing. I only want the incrementing behaviour for the existing unknown ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is by design, it is called [Halloween protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/halloween-protection). To achieve what you want (that is a **one time**) use an updatable CTE:

```
with cte as (
SELECT Column,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rn
FROM Table
WHERE Column IS NULL)
UPDATE t
SET t.Column = m.max + t.rn
FROM cte t
JOIN (
SELECT MAX(Column) as max 
FROM Table) m;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. SQL2008 complained a little about the syntax, but they were trivial to fix: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` --> `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col)`, and `JOIN (...) m` --> `JOIN (...) m ON 1=1`